# Difference of Two Cells in An Array of Shared Memory (Concurrency)

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads, mutex

I have an array in shared memory in a concurrent program, where each thread is directly associated with one cell in the array.  I have a function that is supposed to get the difference between the cell that the thread is associated with with and one of the neighboring cells that that thread isn't associated it.  I'm not sure how to organize the `mutex`s to protect the memory when a thread is accessing a its own cell or its neighboring cell in the most efficient way.  This is what I currently have, but I'm not sure if there's a better way or not.

```
// Assume `myArray` is a global int array used for sharing resources between the threads.  
// Assume `semaphoreArray` is an array of pthread `mutex`s with same size as `my_array`.

int difference (int id, int neighbor) // id allows us to identify the thread
{
    int currentIdsValue;
    int neighboringIdsValue;

    pthread_mutex_lock (& (semaphoreArray[id]));
    currentIdsValue = myArray[id];
    pthread_mutex_unlock (& (semaphoreArray[id]));

    pthread_mutex_lock (& (semaphoreArray[neighbor]));
    neighboringIdsValue = myArray[neighbor];
    pthread_mutex_unlock (& (semaphoreArray[neighbor]));

    return (currentIdsValue - neighboringIdsValue);
}
```

I'm wondering if I should be using two semaphore arrays for each cell being accessed in the array.

**Note**: The `pthread` library is required, can't use `std::thread`, unfortunately.

Comment: Can I ask what type is `myArray`?

Comment: It is `int`, sorry.  Updated now.

Comment: Good. And what are the producer/consumer dynamic of the different threads accessing `myArray`. All of the can both write a specific cell it and read it?

Comment: There is no writing at all in this function, however, another function does allow writing to myArray, but only one thread can write to one cell in the array (to its associated cell), no threads can write to other cells but their own.  The only time threads access each other’s cells is when reading them in this function.

Comment: So what you have for the shared resource, which is a single cell of type int, is a scenario of single producer multiple consumers.

Comment: Then I think there's no need for all the multiple semaphores. You just want to make sure you're not reading anything while it's being written. There's no contention to write, and reading simultaneously isn't at risk of race condition.

Comment: If you'd like you can add to the answer the fact of what thread is reading and writing what data, and I could phrase an with at attempt to provide a comprehensive advice.

Comment: @joe_04_04 using 2 semaphores is necessary in your case (i.e `id` isn't `neighbor`). You need only 2 semaphores, not an array of semaphores to in your current code snippet requirement.